# How to add executable to path on gem install with rubygems?

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems

I've created a program that I want to bundle into a gem that will add the executable located in the `bin` directory to the path. I'm wondering if there is something inside the gemspec that I have to set to make this happen, or if it's something else. I want to be able to use `gem install gem_name` and it will add the executable to the path. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the executables in the gemspec file:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'hola'
  s.version     = '0.0.1'
  s.executables << 'hola'
end
```

http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable

Comment: Yeah I saw that in the guides. Does that add it to the path?

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but I believe it will. Or more specifically, the gem will prompt you to install the binary when you install the gem.